# Spring AOP for database operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am working in a spring,hibernate project and database is oracle. I have DAO layer for persistence related operations.

In all my tables, I have `create_date` and `update_date` columns representing the timestamp when a row is inserted and updated in the tables respectively.

There is a requirement that I have to update the above two mentioned timestamp columns of that particular table for which the request is meant to whenever any insert/update operation happens.For example, If my DAO layer has two methods, say m1 and m2 responsible for impacting t1 and t2 tables respectively. Now, if m1 method is invoked, then timestamp columns of t1 table will be updatedi.e. For insert, `create_date` column will be updated and for any update `update_date` column will be updated.

I have idea of Spring AOP so I was thinking to use AOP to implement the above requirement, though, i am not quite sure if it can be achieved using AOP.

Please let me know if I can use AOP to fulfill this requirement. And if it is possible, then please provide me the inputs how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented update date feature for one of the modules in my application using Spring AOP.
PFB code for your reference

Hope this will help.
I wonder if one can have pointcuts for variable as well.I know its might not possible with spring's aspect j implementation.But any work around guys :P

```
    **
    * @author Vikas.Chowdhury
    * @version $Revision$ Last changed by $Author$ on $Date$ as $Revision$
    */
   @Aspect
   @Component
public class UpdateDateAspect
{
    @Autowired
    private ISurveyService surveyService;

    Integer surveyId = null;

    Logger gtLogger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.service.impl.*.saveSurvey*(..)))")
    public void updateDate()
    {

    }

    @Around("updateDate()")
    public Object myAspect(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
    {

        // retrieve the runtime method arguments (dynamic)
        Object returnVal = null;
        for (final Object argument : pjp.getArgs())
        {

            if (argument instanceof SurveyHelper)
            {
                SurveyHelper surveyHelper = (SurveyHelper) argument;
                surveyId = surveyHelper.getSurveyId();

            }

        }
        try
        {
            returnVal = pjp.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            gtLogger.debug("Unable to use JointPoint :(");
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    @After("updateDate()")
    public void updateSurveyDateBySurveyId() throws Exception
    {
        if (surveyId != null)
        {
            surveyService.updateSurveyDateBySurveyId(surveyId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an Hibernate interceptor instead, that's what they are for. For example, the entities that need such fields could implement the following interface:

```
public interface Auditable {
    Date getCreated();
    void setCreated(Date created);
    Date getModified();
    void setModified(Date modified);
}
```

Then the interceptor always sets the modified field on save, and only sets the created field when it's not already set.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have been asking for a Spring AOP solution to your question, I would like to point out that the same result can be achieved using database triggers, e. g. automatically setting the `created` timestamp during `INSERT` operations and the `modified` timestamp during `UPDATE` statements.

This may be a good solution, especially if not all your DB calls are going through the AOP-captured logic (e. g. when bypassing your pointcut definition because a method does not fit the pattern or even bypassing the code completely using a standalone SQL client), so that you could enforce the modified timestamp even when somebody updates the entries from a different application.

It would have the drawback that you need to define the triggers on all affected tables, though.

Comment: I always think of adding triggers to the database for this sort of thing. But then there's the dilemma of how much logic do you put in the database? I usually go with having all logic in code and no logic in the database. What's your approach @axel-knauf?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with Spring AOP using a `@Before` advice. If you pass an entity to a create method have an advice set the `create_date` and for an update method the `update_date`. You may want to consider the following to make your job easier:

- Have all entities implement a common interface to set `create_date` and `update_date`. This allows you to have a common advice without having to resort to reflection.
- Have a naming convention to identify create and update methods on our DAOs. This will make your point cuts simpler.

Comment: But, how will I get to know which table should this occur?

Comment: You said it's for all your tables.

Comment: what i mean to say is that in my DAO layer, let's say I have two methods, say m1 and m2 impacting t1 and t2 tables respectively. Now suppose m1 method is invoked, then my aspect will be called which will be responsible for update the timestamp columns. But how will my aspect get to know which table it has to perform operation? In this case, it should update t1 table..

Comment: why does the aspect need to know which table is being inserted into? Its only responsibility is to set the timestamp in the object before your dao persists the object into the database

Comment: Heck, i don't even think you need to resort to AOP. If you have a common interface which is responsible for persisting all objects into the db, say a `CommonDao` which has methods `save`, `update` & `delete`, then just setting the timestamps there will be enough. If you don't have such a `CommonDao`, you really should think about it, since it significantly reduces your coupling with hibernate.

Comment: Yes, I do have CommonDao..and I can set those fields in the DAO methods itself without resorting to AOP..I only wanted to know if this can be done through AOP i.e. can i insert/update tables through AOP?

Comment: The advice doesn't have to know the table, it just has to know the entity. You can run any code you want in an advice.

Comment: @anand AOP can execute arbitrary code, *what* that code does is not relevant. But that's not what you actually want to do here, you just want to set a value on the model--you don't need to do any database work in the code at all.